# If $f(x) =\int^{8\sin x}_{-3} (\cos(t^7)+t)dt$ then what is $f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

What I am really asking is if $$f(x) =\int^{8\sin x}_{-3} (\cos(t^7)+t)dt$$ then what is $f'(x)$?

The way I approached the question was by taking the derivative of $(\cos(t^7)+t)dt$, which is $-\sin(t^7)7t^6+1$, and then sub out $t$ for $8\sin(x)$ 
and $-3$ to get:

$-[\sin([8\sin(x)]^7)]7([8\sin(x)]^6)+1-(-[\sin(-2187)]5103+1)$

However, this does not seem correct to me. As well, I am not sure where to go from here, or how to find $f'(x)$. So, does anyone know how this answer can be found?

Comment: You can do \int_a^b which gives you $\int_a^b.$

Comment: $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\int_{-3}^{8\sin(x)}\left(\cos\left(t^7\right)+t\right)\space\text{d}t\right)=$$
$$8\cos(x)\left(\cos(2097152\sin^7(x))+8\sin(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the chain rule where the outer function is simply $\int_{-3}^x$ and the inner function is $8\sin(x)$, and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. (I may have flipped "outer" and "inner". Play with it until you get it right.)